# In javascript is it legal to create a new instance of an object from one of its methods?

Tags: javascript, oop

For instance, is the following code legal?

```
function RandomObject() {
    this.method = function () {
        return new RandomObject();
    };
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll go to jail for that.

Comment: Immoral as it may be, jail is indeed out of the question.

Comment: You might want to read about [TIAS](http://andyburkhardt.com/2012/01/24/try-it-and-see-what-happens/).

Comment: Some say that JavaScript's behaviour resembles Lisp/Scheme more than C++/Java. With languages like that as long as it works (meaning compiles) there is no right or wrong, there's only commonplace and less commonplace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. Just make sure you don't put that in the constructor, else you'll get an infinite loop!